# Agregar una nueva versión de php a wampserver (versión 2.0)

Tags: php, wamp

para la universidad hemos estado trabajando con wampserver y ese es el programa que necesito para hacer las asignaciones y cosas al respecto, quería preguntar si era posible agregar una nueva versión de php (ya sea la versión 5.6 o 7) a esta versión de wamp que es un poco más antigua, ya había visto esta página: http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/ pero no puedo instalar las versiones de php de ese sitio web para el wampserver que utilizo (parecen no ser compatibles), que es lo que podría hacer? Tengo que borrar el wampserver que tengo instalado e instalar el nuevo? Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Y por que no utilizar XAMPP? ya incluye las ultimas versiones de PHP [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/download.html)

Comment: oh es que ese es el que nos están pidiendo en la universidad, si pudiera usara otro web server pero estoy limitado a ese

Comment: WAMP, XAMPP no son mas que un asistente de administracion del stack PHP y MySQL y Apache, Ambos utilizan el mismo servidor web no veo cual es la limitacion, personalmente ya hace tiempo que no los utilizo pero WAMP siempre fue muy engorroso para configurar te recomiendo descargar una version actualizada y desinstalar la actual ya que si lo haces de manera manual al menos en Windows PHP suele fallar muchos modulos

Comment: vale, entonces si me toca hacer asi pues no hay de otra, muchas gracias

Comment: Lo más recomendable es desinstalar la versión de wampserver que tiene e instalar una más actual, o que limitaciones tienes para no hacerlo?

[WampServer](https://www.wampserver.com/es)

Comment: ninguna, lo importante es que use wampserver @MRDev